# Why do different versions of Silverlight assemblies have the same version number?

Tags: .net, silverlight, versioning

Why do different versions of Silverlight assemblies have the same version number?

```
Location: ...\Silverlight\v3.0\System.Core.dll 
Name: System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 

Location: ...\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Core.dll 
Name: System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 

Location: ...\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\System.Core.dll 
Name: System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
```

While standard .net has different version numbers

```
Location: ...\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll 
Name: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 

Location: ...\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll 
Name: System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Comment: I've always wanted to know that. I figured I just must be missing something.

Answer (score 4):

With .NET, for a signed (.snk) assembly, the very first reason why you would not change an assembly version number  is to ensure the assembly's strong name will stay the same. This way, without messing with .config files or custom policies, any client that was build with a reference to your assembly will still be able to load without complaining.

By default (without defining [assemblies redirections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1%28VS.80%29.aspx)), if you change the version, your assembly's strong name will be changed as well, and all existing assemblies build against the previous version will fail to run.

If you never change the version, of course, you'll have to make sure you don't break these same client with different classes or methods signatures.

That's the reason why most of the time, developers tend to keep the same version ... forever, when it's possible, and this is true for the [CoreCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721609.aspx) (Silverlight's CLR) as well as the .NET CLR.

In the case of the .NET CLR though, the fact that they changed the version actually poses some problems for existing .NET apps. Sometimes, existing .NET 2 applications need to add this to the .config file in a .NET 4 context:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

You can look at this article that explains how complex all this can be behind the scene: [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)

Comment: This might explain the silverlight assemblies being the same but does not explain why silverlight and WP7 assemblies have the same version number.

Comment: If assemblies built for SL are somewhat compatible for WP7 without rewrite, that could explain it.

Answer (score 3):

The exact same thing happened with the base class libraries (like System.dll) for the desktop versions of .NET 2.0, 2.0SP1, 2.0SP2, 3.0, 3.0SP1, 3.5 and 3.5SP1, they all have the exact same [AssemblyVersion], 2.0.0.0.  Not until .NET 4.0 did this version get bumped to 4.0.0.0

The assembly version represents the *public* interface of an assembly.  A breaking change in the types members that are accessible to other assemblies requires a new [AssemblyVersion].  Necessarily so, because that requires client code that uses these types to be recompiled.  I checked for the System.Core.dll versions you mentioned.  Bit of a painful slog through the Reflector export output for the assembly.  Plenty of changes in the private and internal classes and methods.  But *not* the public ones, the same types and methods.

Not entirely true, and this happened in the desktop version as well, the StrongBox class acquired a default constructor in version 4.0.  Saving grace perhaps is that the constructor is documented as "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."  And that specifically in Silverlight an app that targets 4.0 is never going to see the 3.0 version of that class by accident, unlike the desktop case.

Comment: Hans. This might make sense for Silverlight 3 and Silverlight 4 as you might be able to argue they are the same runtime. But not for Windows Phone Assemblies which are obviously a differnt public API.

Comment: I don't have it to check, but I don't see why it would be different.  Just Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping the Silverlight 4 framework from using the 2.0.5.0 version of System.Core. The .NET 3.5 framework shipped with version 2.0 of System.Web. However, the .NET 4 framework ships with a newer version of System.Core.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. ALL version of ALL Silverlight files are the same. Even though they are clearly different files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they don't want the developer to recompile the Silverlight application  to target different version of Sliverlight Framework...

Comment: That doesnt work for windows phone assemblies as if you done recompile them they wont run.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the development team forgetting to change the version numbers and not having a check list, but I'm not 100% sure.  There is no mechanism that automates this task b/c there is no central compiler.  Each user in this development group can compile this code assembly as long as they have the strong name with the public key token.  I am interested in the complete answer from an expert on this subject.

Comment: These are the assemblies that MS ships. Surely you don't think that the MS development team forgot to change version numbers, do you?

Comment: In any mature development process there is a [build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) that automates the compilation of assemblies for the whole team's changes, so there is conceptually a centralized compiler. Individual developers would not be responsible for creating the assemblies that actually get released. The build system produces these.

Comment: Really? I thought they created a assembly using a strong key, added the strong key to the assembly and stored that strong key under a unique id. That unique ID is the public key token. The version is set by the last person who compiled the assembly for that project. since you can have multiple projects in a signle solution, each project can potentially have its own signed assembly depending on the project type.  The build system sounds cool, I'll have to investigate it. Thanks for the info.